running Jupyter7 ipynb script on PowerShell, error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.services'
I encountered an error when running Jupyter7 ipynb script on PowerShell, which indicated: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.services'."
detail code：
PS C:\Users\Administrator> jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute --inplace C:\Users\Administrator\ttee.ipynb | python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-nbconvert-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from nbconvert.nbconvertapp import main
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py", line 187, in <module>
    class NbConvertApp(JupyterApp):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py", line 246, in NbConvertApp
    Options include {get_export_names()}.
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\base.py", line 151, in get_export_names
    e = get_exporter(exporter_name)(config=config)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\base.py", line 110, in get_exporter
    exporter = items[0].load()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 202, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_contrib_nbextensions\nbconvert_support\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .collapsible_headings import ExporterCollapsibleHeadings
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_contrib_nbextensions\nbconvert_support\collapsible_headings.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.services.config import ConfigManager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.services'
PS C:\Users\Administrator>

I have added the environment variable:
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
C:\Users\Administrator
Who has encountered or resolved this problem？
